# How to create own login form in Ion Auth for CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Im trying to use Ion Auth to protect admin area on my site.

I installed Ion Auth (added tables, copied files).

I added file application/system/core/MY_Controller.php which looks like this:

```
<?php
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    //Class-wide variable to store user object in.
    protected $the_user;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin() ) 
        {
            redirect('/auth/login');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In all my controllers in admin area I changed CI_Controller to Admin_Controller, like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Start extends Admin_Controller 
{
public function index()
{
        $this->load->view('layout/_header');
        $this->load->view('layout/_left');
        $this->load->view('admin/start');
        $this->load->view('layout/_footer');
}
}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to create own login form wrapped with my layout views.

I have no idea how to do it. In 'auth/login' controller view is loaded in some weird way:

```
$this->_render_page('auth/login', $this->data);
```

**Can somebody help me to write login form, which will be compatybile with my method for loading views?**

I mean that method:

```
$this->load->view('layout/_header');
$this->load->view('layout/_left');
$this->load->view('admin/login'); // i want to load login form here
$this->load->view('layout/_footer');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to read this: http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/ 
login view:

```
<div id="infoMessage"><?php echo $message;?></div>

<?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>

  <p>
    <?php echo lang('login_identity_label', 'identity');?>
    <?php echo form_input($identity);?>
  </p>

  <p>
    <?php echo lang('login_password_label', 'password');?>
    <?php echo form_input($password);?>
  </p>

  <p>
    <?php echo lang('login_remember_label', 'remember');?>
    <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"');?>
  </p>


  <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('login_submit_btn'));?></p>

<?php echo form_close();?>

<p><a href="forgot_password"><?php echo lang('login_forgot_password');?></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

```
    // Check if the user is already logged in       
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        // If not, we send him to the login Page
        redirect('admin/user/login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```